# How to merge xml tags based on two different tags?

Tags: xslt, merge, sum, xslt-1.0

In the below sample xml ASNOutDesc can have multiple ASNOutDistro's and each ASNOutDistro can have multiple ASNOutCtn's, under each ASNOutCtn there can be multiple ASNOutItem, All items under each ASNOutCtn must be merged and the unit_qty must be added. Iam trying with the below xslt, but it is merg

**Input XML:**

```
<ASNoutDesc>
  <ASNOutDesc>
    <to_location>14</to_location>
    <from_location>777</from_location>
    <asn_nbr>Bol1</asn_nbr>
    <container_qty>3</container_qty>
    <shipment_date>2012-04-20T15:37:30.757</shipment_date>
    <ASNOutDistro>
      <distro_nbr>101</distro_nbr>
      <distro_doc_type>A</distro_doc_type>
      <ASNOutCtn>
        <container_id>1</container_id>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-1</item_id>
          <unit_qty>2</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-1</item_id>
          <unit_qty>2</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
      </ASNOutCtn>
    </ASNOutDistro>
    <ASNOutDistro>
      <distro_nbr>102</distro_nbr>
      <distro_doc_type>A</distro_doc_type>
      <ASNOutCtn>
        <container_id>2</container_id>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-1</item_id>
          <unit_qty>2</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-2</item_id>
          <unit_qty>2</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-2</item_id>
          <unit_qty>2</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
      </ASNOutCtn>
      <ASNOutCtn>
        <container_id>3</container_id>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-1</item_id>
          <unit_qty>2</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-2</item_id>
          <unit_qty>2</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
      </ASNOutCtn>
    </ASNOutDistro>
  </ASNOutDesc>
</ASNoutDesc>
```

**Required output:**

```
<ASNoutDesc>
  <ASNOutDesc>
    <to_location>14</to_location>
    <from_location>777</from_location>
    <asn_nbr>Bol1</asn_nbr>
    <container_qty>3</container_qty>
    <shipment_date>2012-04-20T15:37:30.757</shipment_date>
    <ASNOutDistro>
      <distro_nbr>101</distro_nbr>
      <distro_doc_type>A</distro_doc_type>
      <ASNOutCtn>
        <container_id>1</container_id>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-1</item_id>
          <unit_qty>4</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
      </ASNOutCtn>
    </ASNOutDistro>
    <ASNOutDistro>
      <distro_nbr>102</distro_nbr>
      <distro_doc_type>A</distro_doc_type>
      <ASNOutCtn>
        <container_id>2</container_id>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-1</item_id>
          <unit_qty>2</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-2</item_id>
          <unit_qty>4</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
      </ASNOutCtn>
      <ASNOutCtn>
        <container_id>3</container_id>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-1</item_id>
          <unit_qty>2</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-2</item_id>
          <unit_qty>2</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
      </ASNOutCtn>
    </ASNOutDistro>
  </ASNOutDesc>
</ASNoutDesc>
```

As shown above it has to merge the items in each ASNOutCtn under each ASNOutDistro.

**XSLT Iam using:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:key name="kByI" match="ASNOutItem" use="item_id"/>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:param name="pNewValueQty"/>
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
        <xsl:with-param name="pNewValueQty" select="$pNewValueQty"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ASNOutItem[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kByI',item_id)[1])]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*">
        <xsl:with-param name="pNewValueQty" select="sum(key('kByI',item_id)/unit_qty)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="ASNOutItem"/>
  <xsl:template match="unit_qty/text()">
    <xsl:param name="pNewValueQty"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$pNewValueQty"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output I got:**

```
<ASNoutDesc>
  <ASNOutDesc>
    <to_location>14</to_location>
    <from_location>777</from_location>
    <asn_nbr>Bol1</asn_nbr>
    <container_qty>3</container_qty>
    <shipment_date>2012-04-20T15:37:30.757</shipment_date>
    <ASNOutDistro>
      <distro_nbr>101</distro_nbr>
      <distro_doc_type>A</distro_doc_type>
      <ASNOutCtn>
        <container_id>1</container_id>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-1</item_id>
          <unit_qty>8</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
      </ASNOutCtn>
    </ASNOutDistro>
    <ASNOutDistro>
      <distro_nbr>102</distro_nbr>
      <distro_doc_type>A</distro_doc_type>
      <ASNOutCtn>
        <container_id>2</container_id>
        <ASNOutItem>
          <item_id>item-2</item_id>
          <unit_qty>6</unit_qty>
        </ASNOutItem>
      </ASNOutCtn>
      <ASNOutCtn>
        <container_id>3</container_id>
      </ASNOutCtn>
    </ASNOutDistro>
  </ASNOutDesc>
</ASNoutDesc>
```

-My code is merging all items in the xml.Please help me in getting required output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the question to cut down the length of the XML pastes? Please ensure only enough code is posted in order that we understand what you need / what's going wrong. If code merely repeats in different, but ultimately similarly-structured iterations, these can be omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you went wrong was to forget to factor in the parent nodes in the grouping of ASNOutItem nodes. Your key definition should be keyed on a untion of item_id and the ASNOutCtn node which is the parent of ASNOutItem, as the grouping does not cross ASNOutCtn boundaries.

This style-sheet is what you want ...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="kByI" match="ASNOutItem" use="concat(item_id,'+',generate-id(parent::*))"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ASNOutCtn">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::ASNOutItem)]"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates
    select="ASNOutItem[
     generate-id(.) =
     generate-id( key('kByI',concat(item_id,'+',generate-id(parent::*)))[1])]"
    mode="merge"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ASNOutItem" mode="merge">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(self::unit_qty)]"/>
  <unit_qty>
    <xsl:value-of select="sum(
      key('kByI',concat(item_id,'+',generate-id(parent::*)))/unit_qty)" />
  </unit_qty>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: .Thank U Sooo much. Iam very much new to xslt and even software industry. Currently Iam working on an integration project, most of the project includes transformations. Can you please help me where I could find appropriate material which starts from basics of xml processing. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a `sum(ASNOutItem/item_id)`?

Sorry if I ask, but in my opinion if I look at that code in a year it will take a tons of time to understand what I did and what it is doing. I would prefer to do something like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<ASNoutDesc>
    <ASNOutDesc>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*[name() != 'ASNOutDistro']"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="ASNOutDistro">
            <xsl:copy-of select="*[name() != 'ASNOutCtn']"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="ASNOutCtn">
                <ASNOutCtn>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="*[name() != 'ASNOutItem']"/>
                    <ASNOutItem>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="ASNOutItem[1]/*[name() != 'unit_qty']"/>
                        <unit_qty>
                            <xsl:value-of select="sum(ASNOutItem/*/unit_qty)"/>
                        </unit_qty>
                    </ASNOutItem>
                </ASNOutCtn>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </ASNOutDesc>
</ASNoutDesc>
```